# Docker backing filesystem as AWS efs

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am mounting an `AWS efs filesystem` on /var/lib/docker and using it as the default docker backing filesystem. Storage driver is `overlay2`. I see in the docs that overlay2 only supports `xfs and ext`. My aim is to mount this backing filesystem on multiple machines so that all those machines have the image data but multiple mount is not supported by aws ebs(being a ext4 and a supported backing fs by overlay2). One way could by that is pull the images on an `ext4 fs` and `cp` the image data into the efs but it would be too time taking. What could be another way to go about this?

Comment: I don't think you can share `/var/lib/docker` between machines at all.

Comment: I just want to read the /var/lib/docker data(on efs) in those machines. It won't be acting as the default directory for docker daemon on that machine.

Comment: I just want one machine that can write data to the efs's `/var/lib/docker` and act as the docker daemon's default dir on that particular machine.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "don't do that" because `/var/lib/docker` is not designed to be shared by multiple daemons. You'll find race conditions, erroneous output about networks and containers that don't exist locally, and other errors that won't be fixed/supported.

Instead, put a registry near your cluster, in the same VPC/AZ, and have your nodes pull from that cluster. Or have a look at the work done to support estargz in runtimes like containerd which can start running a container before the layers are completely pulled.